# updating neo4j database using java program

Tags: java, neo4j

I am creating neo4j graph database (.DB file) using java program by inputting one excel file. I can update this .DB file with another excel file but once this .DB file is opened in Neo4j after that I am unable to update this existing database by inputting another excel file it is showing exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, D:\innoneuron\Transform\Feature1_Automatic_Tagging\Feature1_Automatic_Tagging\test.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:366)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:181)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:71)
    at feature3.AutomatedGraph.startDb(AutomatedGraph.java:88)
    at feature3.AutomatedGraph.main(AutomatedGraph.java:50)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@5a4aa2f2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:343)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@f0f2775' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:164)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UpgradingStoreVersionNotFoundException: 'neostore.nodestore.db' does not contain a store version, please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreMigrator.needsMigration(StoreMigrator.java:135)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.getParticipantsEagerToMigrate(StoreUpgrader.java:268)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:344)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507)
    ... 11 more
```

Is there any way to update this .DB file with different input excels?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I am facing in updating the database after once it is open is due to difference in the installed Neo4j database version and jar file version which is using in the project.
Use the same version jar for the Neo4j version.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Per the initial cause of the exception:

> please ensure that the original database was shut down in a clean state

Are you sure that you correctly shut down the database at the end of its creation, when you imported the first Excel file? You need to call [`GraphDatabaseService.shutdown()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#shutdown--) before exiting.

Comment: Yes I am shutting down the database in the program at the end of its creation.But the thing is that once the .DB file is opened in Neo4j after that I am unable to update it.But if I do not open this .DB file than it can be updated.I am using Neo4j 3.0.6 (exe) version.

Comment: You should update your question with that relevant part of the scenario, then: describe the full steps leading do the impossibility to reopen the database.

Comment: I have updated the question hoping for answer that can help me to solve my problem.I have tried after shutting down the database but doesn't solve the problem.